# Importing Module issue (name of project and name of module are the same)

Tags: python-3.x, design-patterns, module, namespaces

So I am having an issue trying to import some modules right now because the name of the project is same as the module name. At least thats what I think.

I am trying to run the test_aws_file.py main file. That file is trying to import my.test.utils.util_file, but it is getting this error: 
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'my.test.aws', so seems like i can import up to 'my.test' then when i add .aws then it would cause the error

test_aws_file.py import coding:

`sys.path.insert(1, os.path.abspath('.'))
print(sys.path)
from my.test.aws.utils.utils_file import UtilsFile`

project name (i do have a **init**.py in all directories): my.test.aws

my/

```
test/
   aws/
      utils/
          util_file.py
```

test_aws/

```
 test_aws_file.py
```

Answer (score 1):

you should have `__init__.py` files in your directories to make those packages, otherwise the import wont work.

Comment: do you still need help

Comment: Yes I do. Still can’t import